# Accessing post custom fields in Wordpress sidebar widget

Tags: wordpress, widget, sidebar

I'm building a simple sidebar widget to display a loop of a custom post type "shows".

Each "show" has about 3 custom fields, which i'd like to output via the loop as well. This is the code i'm using:

This is the loop within my plugin code:

```
<?php
// WIDGET CODE GOES HERE
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'shows', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $month = get_post_meta($post->ID,'month-abbreviation',true);
    $date = get_post_meta($post->ID,'date',true);
    $citystate = get_post_meta($post->ID,'city-state',true); ?> 
    <article class="sidebar-show clearfix">
        <a class="show-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="date-box">
                <span class="month"><?php echo $month; ?></span>
                <span class="date"><?php echo $date; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="venue-box">
                <?php echo "<h4>".get_the_title()."</h4>"; ?>
                <?php echo "<p>".$citystate."</p>"; ?> 
            </div>
        </a>
    </article>
<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
<?php 
    echo $after_widget;
  }

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("ShowsSidebarWidget");') );?>
```

This code pulls in the post titles, but doesn't display the custom fields month-abbreviation, date, and city-state.

What's missing here?

EDIT: Removed double quotes after avexdesign's reply.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure $post->ID is available in this context?

maybe you should try: **get_the_ID()** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see a few things you can try.

1. month-abbreviation - should be single quotes. Like 'month-abbreviation'
2. Try taking out:  `$month=`  `$date=` and  `$citystate =`
3. Might need `echo`

So Try:

`echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'month-abbreviation', true);`

`echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'date', true);`

`echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'city-state', true);`

Comment: I tried that out and i'm still getting no output. I think it has something to do with how I form my loop... maybe WP_query.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

`<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'shows', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) ); ?>`

`<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>`

`<span class="month"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'month-abbreviation', true); ?></span>`

`<span class="date"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date', true); ?></span>`

and so on... for your other custom IDs

Comment: you may also need to flush the rewrite rules: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules